# Compute the variance of number of records examined

Tags: probability

I've done the problem, and I think it's right (it's not homework or for a test).  So I'm writing this out in the hope that if I'm wrong, I'll either notice it while explaining it, or that somebody will correct me.  Thanks!

A client's records are present in a list of $n$ records with probability $p$.  If present, the position in the list is uniformly distributed.  What is the variance of the number of records we need to examine if we want to know if the client's records are in the list?

Let $X$ be the number of records examined.  We seek $E(X)$.  By the law of total expectation, we can write $E(X) = E(X|L)P(L) + E(X|L')P(L')$, where $L$ denotes the event "the client is in the list".

If the client is not in the list, we must check all $n$ records.
If the client is in the list, we can stop looking as soon as we find the records.  All positions in the list are equally likely, by hypothesis.  So we must look at an average of $\frac{n}{2}$ records before finding the client records.

Putting this together, we find that $E(X) = n(1-p) + \frac{np}{2} = n - np + \frac{np}{2} = n - \frac{np}{2}$.

Similarly, by the law of total expectation, $E(X^2) = E(X^2|L) P(L) + E(X^2|L') P(L')$.  As above, if the records are not in the list, then we must examine them all, so that $E(X^2|L')$ is $n^2$.

If the customer's records are in the list, then their position in the list is uniformly distributed.  From this we know that the variance $V(X|L)$ is $\frac{n^2}{12}$, so that $E(X^2|L) = \frac{13n^2}{12}$.  We put these pieces together to compute

$$
\begin{align}
E(X^2) &= E(X^2|L)P(L) + E(X^2|L')P(L') \\
       &= \frac{13pn^2}{12} + (1 - p)n^2
\end{align}
$$

Finally, we can compute the variance of $V(X)$ as

$$
\begin{align}
V(X) &= E(X^2) - E(X)^2 \\
      &= \frac{13pn^2}{12} + (1 - p)n^2 - \left(n - \frac{np}{2}\right)^2 \\
      &= \frac{13pn^2}{12} + n^2 - pn^2 - n^2 + pn^2 - \frac{n^2p^2}{4} \\
      &= \frac{13pn^2}{12} - \frac{n^2p^2}{4}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 3):

$E(X)=(1-p)n+pE(N)$
where $N$ is uniform on $1,2,...,n$ so $E(N)=(1/n)\sum_{k=1}^n k=\frac{n(n+1)}{2n}=(n+1)/2.$

$E(X^2)=(1-p)n^2+pE(N^2)$ where $E(N^2)=(1/n)\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6n}$

$Var(X)=(1-p)n^2 +\frac{p(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}-\left[ (1-p)n+p(n+1)/2  \right ]^2. $